# Change category base based on category

Tags: categories, permalinks

How can I change the permalink based on the category? I would like to change the category base based on its category.

I want the output to be like this:

1. /news/category1
2. /articles/category2
3. /articles/category3

In short, they're all just categories in one POST TYPE which is "post" but only the permalinks are different.

PS. I know I can just build a CPT for this. Just trying not to do it if there's a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin like [Enhanced Custom Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-custom-permalinks/) which will allow you to set your own customised permalinks.